# Mapping pandas' Series to dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, converting

I've got something really simple this time where I'm mapping pandas' `Series` to  `dataclass`es with a oneliner helper function (as I have several models):

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import Any
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

def create_dataclass(data: pd.Series, factory: Any) -> Any:
    return factory(**{f.name: data[f.name] for f in fields(factory)})
```

I call it like this:

```py
@dataclass
class Person:
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

@dataclass
class Employee(Person):
    company: str

def create_employees(data: pd.DataFrame) -> List[Employee]:
    return [create_dataclass(r, Employee) for i, r in data.iterrows()]
```

---

Do you think it still could be more pythonic?

Answer (score 1):

Looks very pythonic to me.

Thumbs up, LGTM, ship it!

---

Ok, fine, I have a few minor remarks.

Maybe the `Any` annotations could be
finessed a bit to be more informative?
Or maybe just drop the `-> Any:`.

---

```
    return factory(**{f.name: data[f.name]  for f in fields(factory)})
```

The `**` double star is as pythonic as it gets.
But notice that what we really care about is `name`.
So perhaps

```
from operator import attrgetter

    ...
    return factory(**{name: data[name] for name in map(attrgetter('name'), fields(factory))})
```

Hmmm, not sure that longer works out to a win.
Prolly better to keep the code as-is.

---

```
    ... for _, r in data.iterrows()]
```

nit: Prefer `row` over `r`. Whatever.

Like I said, ship it.